# Ant exec task and check using some ksh script

Tags: ant

I'm facing a problem using Ant

I'd like to check for the end of a long process, without using a nasty `<sleep>` command.

In my Ant target, I'm launching

```
<exec executable="my long process" />
```

When I'm manually checking for the end of the process, I'm using this following command :

```
watch " "check ksh script" | grep "ONLINE" "
```

When the grep returns something, it means my process has ended (because the check ksh script outputs ONLINE)

How can I perform the same check in Ant ?

I'm trying to use something like the following (to simulate the watch command)

```
<exec executable="my long process" />
<waitfor maxwait="2" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="5" checkeveryunit="second">
    // do something here to check "ONLINE"
</waitfor>
```

But I don't know what to put in the `<waitfor>`

Comment: Is the "long process" something that completes with an exit value like 0?  If so, you use resultproperty in the exec and test when the value of the property in the waitfor block changes.  From the docs, it seems like you could not set the property prior to the exec and then use an "isset" test in the waitfor conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The long Process asks several other processes to start. I Can check if they are Online with The "check ksh scrpt" which outputs "offline" or "online" When called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways with Ant to execute your check script and then test its output, but it cannot fit the `waitfor` tasks which is accepting just one condition.

You could try with scripting though.
See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#scriptcondition

It should look something like that:

```
<scriptcondition language="javascript" value="true">
    var p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ksh check");
    p.waitFor();
    var reader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    var out = org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.safeReadFully(reader);
    self.setValue(out.contains("ONLINE"));
</scriptcondition>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why this "cannot fit the waitfor tasks which is accepting just one condition"?  The <scriptcondition> works inside a <waitfor> according to the docs.  Seems like this approach would work in the "//do something here" section of the question.

Comment: `waitfor` is expecting only one condition. In your use case you would need at least an exec task and a condition. Both cannot fit in `waitfor`.

Comment: executing your scriptcondition gives me "javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Runtime" is not defined."

Comment: I added BSF-2.4.0.jar, commons-logging-1.1.2.jar and js.jar (rhino1_7R4) but I still get org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: Runtime is not defined.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that Runtime was not "imported" so I wrote java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...). But now I have : Java class "java.io.InputStreamReader" has no public instance field or method named "InputStreamReader", which is strange since there is a constructor InputStreamReader (Inputstream) in the InputStreamReader class

Comment: The line about the InputStreamReader was incorrect, I have fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works. I also added p.waitFor() after the exec command, to wait for the secondary thread to finish before checking anything